# Redis Sentinel false failovers

Tags: linux, php, haproxy, redis

I'm having problems with Redis.

I have 3 servers. Each server have 10 Redises working on different port. Also, each server has one Sentinel instance.

Also, there are 5 application servers. Each server has HaProxy which checks from pool which Redis server is the master and redirect traffic to him.

So, application always uses 127.0.0.1:port no matter which server is the Redis master.

I'm having trouble with false positives. This is my log:

```
[37338] 29 Apr 07:51:36.813 # Connection with slave ip1:6388 lost.
[37338] 29 Apr 07:51:37.399 # Connection with slave ip3:6388 lost.
[7244] 29 Apr 07:51:38.809 * DB saved on disk
[7244] 29 Apr 07:51:38.814 * RDB: 35 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
[37338] 29 Apr 07:51:38.918 * Background saving terminated with success
[37338] 29 Apr 07:51:47.451 * SLAVE OF 192.168.234.ip1:6388 enabled (user request)
[37338] 29 Apr 07:51:47.457 # CONFIG REWRITE executed with success.
[37338] 29 Apr 07:51:47.541 * Connecting to MASTER ip1:6388
[37338] 29 Apr 07:51:47.541 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync started
[37338] 29 Apr 07:51:47.541 * Non blocking connect for SYNC fired the event.
[37338] 29 Apr 07:51:47.541 * Master replied to PING, replication can continue...
[37338] 29 Apr 07:51:47.541 * Partial resynchronization not possible (no cached master)
[37338] 29 Apr 07:51:47.542 * Full resync from master: 0be90102031e58ef358f0ea48e58eeae869902d1:157705847
[37338] 29 Apr 07:51:51.730 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync: receiving 85082188 bytes from master
[37338] 29 Apr 07:51:52.588 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync: Flushing old data
[37338] 29 Apr 07:51:53.011 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync: Loading DB in memory
[37338] 29 Apr 07:51:54.401 * MASTER <-> SLAVE sync: Finished with success
[37338] 29 Apr 07:52:39.072 * 10000 changes in 60 seconds. Saving...
[37338] 29 Apr 07:52:39.083 * Background saving started by pid 27656
```

But nothing happened what would cause this.

I've already had problem when the Sentinel timeout was to low (100ms) so I changed to 5s. There were no timeouts until today.

Also, 5 servers are redundant. When I turn of half of them, application starts to slow down. There are no CPU, Mem, disk issues I can see.

Yesterday, I had issue that application server dropped traffic when half of them were off. Server would start to idle for few seconds and then again works normal. Nginx (front server) uses proxypass to balance traffic to application server.
I doubted on port range (netstat counted more than 90k connections). Also, there were more than 30k connections from 127.0.0.1:someport to 127.0.0.1:redisport in timewait. Application -> Haproxy Redis.

```
net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range = 10000    65535
```

Also, I've turned on:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
```

After that there were no more traffic loses but application is still too slow and there are no obvious reasons for that (cpu, mem, hdd... everything ok).

What can I check more?

Comment: Hi yax, first of all check ss -s and ss -a, to see where the connections are coming from, second tcp_tw_reuse and tcp_tw_recycle have some downsides of their own, read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12719362/1622779). If your design allows you could create multiple upstreams and redis with different ip's to save ports. Give it a go